# Decode JSON from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, decode, encode

I have JSON string in MySQL database like this

```
{
    "string1": {
        "substring1": 1234
    },
    "string2": {
        "substring2": "substring2.1",
        "substring3": "substring3.1",
        "substring4": {
            "substring4.1": 1234,
            "substring4.2": 1234,
            "substring4.3": 1234
        }
    }
}
```

I put those data from MySQL into **$string**, then I decode it with this function

```
$json_a = json_decode($string,true); 
echo $json_a['string1']['substring1'];
```

But the result is nothing.
Then I tried to change the **$string** into

```
$string = '{"string1":{"substring1":1234},"string2":{"substring2":"substring2.1","substring3":"substring3.1","substring4":{"substring4.1":1234,"substring4.2":1234,"substring4.3":1234}}}';
```

Next, I use the same function as above and works fine.
Is there any specific things we should do before decode it from mysql?

Thank you

Comment: What does var_dump($string) look like?

Comment: @MarkusMüller: the result like this String (174) {"string1":{"substring1":1234},"string2":{"substring2":"substring2.1","substring3":"substring3.1","substring4":{"substring4.1":1234,"substring4.2":1234,"substring4.3":1234}}}

Comment: @MarkusMüller how is it?

Answer (score 0):

The outer layer of the data you have is not an array, in fact you don't have any arrays in the data at all. Don't use `[0]` in your PHP.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistaken when posting this question, I already edited the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Access your index with

```
echo $json_a['string1']['substring1'];
```